# jQuery select all except first

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In jQuery how do I use a selector to access all but the first of an element? So in the following code only the second and third element would be accessed. I know I can access them manually but there could be any number of elements so thats not possible. Thanks.

```
<div class='test'></div>
<div class='test'></div>
<div class='test'></div>
```

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831334/jquery-selector-all-but-the-first/18322370#18322370

Answer (score 631, accepted):

```
$("div.test:not(:first)").hide();
```

or:

```
$("div.test:not(:eq(0))").hide();
```

or:

```
$("div.test").not(":eq(0)").hide();
```

or:

```
$("div.test:gt(0)").hide();
```

or: (as per @Jordan Lev's comment):

```
$("div.test").slice(1).hide();
```

and so on.

See:

- http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/
- https://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: Here is a JsPerf comparing all those solutions: http://jsperf.com/fastest-way-to-select-all-expect-the-first-one

Depending on the number of items, `$("li").not(":eq(0)")` seems good.

Comment: @Damien - fastastic! I will add that to my answer in the xmas holidays  :)

Comment: love this list. Just wanted to add: `$("div.test:first").siblings().hide()`. Found it useful for me to start with the first element, then hide all of its siblings even if they aren't found with a common selector.

Comment: Great list! Just a small comment though; I don't think gt is a JQuery function anymore, at least not in the version I use. I get a TypeError: .gt is not a function.

Comment: If your looking for the reverse (select all but last): http://stackoverflow.com/a/36852073/2512022

Comment: @karim79 thank you - what if i want to select all apart from the first AND second?

Comment: `$("div.test").slice(1).hide();` looks most forgiving in case of empty selection...

Comment: Note for speed:  `$("div.test").first().siblings().hide()` is probably going to be the fastest

Comment: @SandyGifford wouldn't that include siblings that are not in the test class? And miss test-class elements that are not siblings?

Comment: @karim79 I don't think `.gt()` is a jQuery method. [Was it ever](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40810197/673991)? So I'd **remove your 2nd to last example** `$("div.test").gt(0).hide();`

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone You are correct.  You can fix this by passing `"div.test"` to `siblings`, but I'm not sure what the performance impact of that would be.

Comment: @SandyGifford agreed, and good save, but that only removes the siblings that are not div.test. It doesn't include the non-siblings that _are_ div.test. So it's still not equivalent to the (working) examples here.

Comment: @Dre I went ahead and removed that .gt() example.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone I guess I misunderstood the problem

Comment: @SandyGifford if you were to make your `.siblings()` and `.siblings('div.test')` ideas into an answer, and mention that it's slightly different from the question (in that it only works for siblings), I'd upvote it. It really is superior in some cases, including the O.P. example. And I'll delete all my comments about it. ;-)

Comment: WARNING: as of jQuery 3.4.0 `:first` and `:eq` are deprecated! [link](https://blog.jquery.com/2019/04/10/jquery-3-4-0-released/)

Comment: So `$("div.test").slice(1)` is the only right solution

Answer (score 37):

Because of the way jQuery selectors are evaluated *right-to-left*, the quite readable `li:not(:first)` is slowed down by that evaluation.

An equally fast and *easy to read* solution is using the function version `.not(":first")`:

e.g.

```
$("li").not(":first").hide();
```

**JSPerf:** http://jsperf.com/fastest-way-to-select-all-expect-the-first-one/6

This is only few percentage points slower than `slice(1)`, but is very readable as "I want all except the first one".

Comment: This is my favourite as well, I find it very clean and easy to read. The intent is unmistakable.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is focused to a extended case derived from the one exposed at top.

Suppose you have group of elements from which you want to hide the child elements except first. As an example:

```
<html>
  <div class='some-group'>
     <div class='child child-0'>visible#1</div>
     <div class='child child-1'>xx</div>
     <div class='child child-2'>yy</div>
  </div>
  <div class='some-group'>
     <div class='child child-0'>visible#2</div>
     <div class='child child-1'>aa</div>
     <div class='child child-2'>bb</div>
  </div>
</html>
```

1. We want to hide all `.child` elements on every group. So this will not help because will hide all `.child` elements except `visible#1`:

   ```
   $('.child:not(:first)').hide();
   ```
2. The solution (in this extended case) will be:

   ```
   $('.some-group').each(function(i,group){
       $(group).find('.child:not(:first)').hide();
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".btn1").click(function(){
          $("div.test:not(:first)").hide();
  });

  $(".btn2").click(function(){
           $("div.test").show();
          $("div.test:not(:first):not(:last)").hide();
  });

  $(".btn3").click(function(){
          $("div.test").hide();
          $("div.test:not(:first):not(:last)").show();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn1">Hide All except First</button>
<button class="btn2">Hide All except First & Last</button>
<button class="btn3">Hide First & Last</button>

<br/>

<div class='test'>First</div>
<div class='test'>Second</div>
<div class='test'>Third</div>
<div class='test'>Last</div>
```