# Bind value to star rating

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I am using a star rating system in my web application. I  am having problem in fetching previously rated value to star's. If user have rated previously [4]. It must be displayed through four star blink. Currently I am saving user vote in database and retriving the rate value. But I don't know how to bind the Rating value to  star.

Here's My Code:
CSS

```
.stars on{background:url(../image/star_on.gif) no-repeat;}
.stars li{
    float:left;
    width:17px;
    height:17px;
   background-image: url( '../image/ratingStarEmpty.gif' );
    list-style-type:none;
    transition:all 0.2s linear;
}
.stars:hover li{
    background-image: url(../image/ratingStarFilled.gif);
}
.stars li:hover ~ li{
   background-image: url( '../image/ratingStarEmpty.gif' );
}
```

Jquery That Return's Star value

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:'User/UserHome.aspx/BindInner',
                data: '{id:'+ id +'}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function(msg)
                {
 var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(msg.d);
                var xml = $(xmlDoc);
                innpageCount = parseInt(xml.find("innerPageCount").eq(0).find("innerPageCount").text());     
                var inncommonload = xml.find("InnerCommentonload");
               // $("#MainBox"+id).find("#dvCustomers1 table").remove();
                inncommonload.each(function () {
 var sno=inncommonload.find("SNo").text();
 var rate=inncommonload.find("Rating").text();
        var star='<ul class="stars"><li class="starvalue" id="1star'+sno+'"  onclick="AnsMark('+sno+',1); return false;"><a></a></li><li class="starrr" id="2star'+sno+'"   onclick="AnsMark('+sno+',2); return false;"></li><li class="starrr" id="3star'+sno+'"  onclick="AnsMark('+sno+',3); return false;"></li><li class="starrr" id="4star'+sno+'"  onclick="AnsMark('+sno+',4); return false;"></li><li class="starrr" id="5star'+sno+'"   onclick="AnsMark('+sno+',5); return false;"></li></ul>';
 });

                },
                failure: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please provide "inncommonload()" .

Comment: inncommonload() is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this answer to solve your problem [jQuery select all except first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259393/jquery-select-all-except-first).

You can round your rate to an integer, select that many stars with jQuery selector and apply some specific css style.

Comment: What can be done with selectors is described here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I want to display star even though they have been not rated. I am geting rated  values from database is in int only. I tried to remove style(without rating) with style (with rating) . But it's not working.

Comment: Maybe because of this `.stars on`? Did you mean `.stars .on`?