# Create a combobox by using HTML item list

Tags: jquery, html, combobox

How can I show only first `li` and hide the others?

I am trying to do a combobox via **jQuery**:

My jQuery script:

```
var drp = $('.drpdiv');

$(drp).each(function(index,value){
    $(this).find('li:first').text()
    $(this).find('li').hide();
    alert($(this).find('li:first').text());
});
```

My html code:

```
<div class="drpdiv">
    <ul class="drp">
        <li>select option...</li>   
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to hide ? or disable ?? question not clear. what is the purpose ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it it with :not selector
For example like in code below

```
var drp = $('.drpdiv');

$(drp).find('li:not(:first)').hide();
```

Also take a look at this answer [jQuery select all except first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259393/jquery-select-all-except-first)

Answer (score 0):

you can hide all the li but give the first li a class and make that li visible.
you can also give the second an other li a class and hide them.

I hope this awnsers you question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Here's your html

```
  <ul class="drp">
    <li>select option...</li>   
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>


<input type="button" class = "show_button" value ="Show" />
```

then here's your script, the first element will only be shown.

```
$('.drp li:gt(0)').hide(); //hide elements
$('.show_button').click(function() {
    $('.drp li:gt(0)').show();
});
```