# jQuery select all except last

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery how can you select all elements but the last?

```
<div class='elem'>1</div>
<div class='elem'>2</div>
<div class='elem'>3</div>
```

For example I want hide div's 1 and 2, but keep three.

Comment: you can hide them all then show the last

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$("div.elem:not(:last)").hide();
```

or

```
$("div.elem").not(":last").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide by nth-child of element as defined below.

```
$("div.elem:not(:nth-child(3))").hide();
```