# Why gt() and lt() are only jQuery selectors, instead eq() is also a method?

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, why only `eq()` is both a selector (:) and a method (.), instead `gt()` and `lt()` are only selectors ("Object doesn't support that property or method")?

Is there a particular reason for this inconsistency/gap of jQuery syntax, that I do not understand?

```js
$("#eq").click(function(){
  alert($("li").eq(0).text());
  $("li").eq(1).css("background-color", "yellow");
});
$("#eq2").click(function(){
  alert($("li:eq(0)").text());
  $("li:eq(1)").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
$("#gt").click(function(){
  $("li").gt(1).css("background-color", "yellow");
});
$("#gt2").click(function(){
  $("li:gt(1)").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
$("#lt").click(function(){
  $("li").lt(1).css("background-color", "yellow");
});
$("#lt2").click(function(){
  $("li:lt(1)").css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="indice">
 <li>Primo capitolo</li>
 <li>Secondo capitolo
  <ul>
   <li>Sottocapitolo</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Terzo capitolo</li>
</ul>
<button id="eq">.eq()</button>
<button id="eq2">:eq()</button><br>
<button id="gt">.gt()</button> <!-- NO -->
<button id="gt2">:gt()</button><br>
<button id="lt">.lt()</button> <!-- NO -->
<button id="lt2">:lt()</button>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not considered useful enough to be a built-in, I suppose. Using `.eq()` instead of `:eq` allows jQuery to use `querySelectorAll` for a massive performance improvement.

In any case, you can use `.slice` like so:

```
$("li").slice(0,4); // :lt(4)
$("li").slice(5); // :gt(4)
```

Alternatively, add them yourself:

```
$.fn.lt = function(n) {return this.slice(0,n);};
$.fn.gt = function(n) {return this.slice(n+1);};
```

Example:

```js
$.fn.lt = function(n) {return this.slice(0,n);};
$.fn.gt = function(n) {return this.slice(n+1);};
$("div").lt(2).css("color", "blue");
$("div").gt(2).css("border", "1px solid red");
$("div").eq(2).css("background-color", "yellow");
```

```html
<div>0</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```