# Add Class to all but first table

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have a page that will have multiple table elements created dynamically.

I need to add a class to every table except the first one.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$(".print-tables").each(function (i, value) {
    if (i !== 0) {
        $(".print-tables").addClass("skip-row");
    }
});
```

This is not working.

What needs to be corrected or edited?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are close but need to select only one table at a time inside the loop. You're adding the class to every `.print-tables` every iteration of the loop.

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259393/jquery-select-all-except-first[/link]

Comment: inside the loop, change `$(".print-tables").addClass("skip-row");` with `$(value).addClass("skip-row");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fewer lines required; Just use the [not](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [first](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selectors to ignore the first element.

```
$(".print-tables:not(:first)").addClass("skip-row");
```

You could use [`.print-tables:gt(0)`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) but the above is more semantic.

You're iterating but adding the class to the whole selection each time. To do it your way you would need to use $(this).

```
$(".print-tables").each(function (i, value) {
    if (i !== 0) {
        $(this).addClass("skip-row");
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0v5vy07e/)

Answer (score 2):

You can put in directly the pseudo-class `:not(:first)` to your selector

`$(".print-tables:not(:first)").addClass('skip-row')`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('.print-tables').each(function (i, value) {
    if (i !== 0) {
        $(this).addClass('skip-row');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/659xzwnu/