# Display unique element using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting, element

I have dynamically generated element and want to sort by the id unique, that is if the id is same thrice show only one.

```
<li id="721" class="mylist"  />        
<li id="721" class="mylist"  />     
<li id="721" class="mylist"  />     

<li id="722" class="mylist"  />        
<li id="722" class="mylist" />     

<li id="723" class="mylist"  />        
<li id="723"  />
```

At the end I want to get

```
<li id="721" class="mylist"  /> 
<li id="722" class="mylist"  />        
<li id="723" class="mylist"  />
```

I am trying jquery script thus

```
var arr = [];
$.each( $('.mylist'), function(){

  var id= this.id;
  if( $.inArray( id, arr ) < 0 ){
     $this.hide(); 
  }

});
```

Comment: You are asking to do unique, what about value of li list? it is having A,I,R

Comment: The ``id`` **must** be unique by default. If you are creating elements with the same ID, you need to redesign your code before doing anything else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery select all except first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259393/jquery-select-all-except-first)

Comment: the value is not needed, we can just remove it

Comment: Your "expected" results are not a unique list.  Perhaps you could reword the title to reflect what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```js
arr = [];
n = 0;
$(".mylist").each(function() {
  if (n == 0 || n != $(this).attr("id")) {
    n = $(this).attr("id");
  } else {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="721" class="mylist">1</li>
<li id="721" class="mylist">2</li>
<li id="721" class="mylist">3</li>

<li id="722" class="mylist">4</li>
<li id="722" class="mylist">5</li>

<li id="723" class="mylist">6</li>
<li id="723" class="mylist">7</li>
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

As @mpf82 mentioned all your IDs have to be unique. You could transfer your ID's to a data attribute.

I made a quick codepen with some comments to explain what i did: https://codepen.io/frankbiemans/pen/xqBxdJ

```
// This var will hold all the unique data ids
var uids = [];

// Collect all different ID's used
$.each( $('.mylist li'), function(){
  // Get the data-id attribute
  var id = $(this).data('id');

  // Only add if the ID is unique
  if($.inArray(id, uids) === -1) {
    uids.push(id);
  }
});

// For each ID in array...
uids.forEach(function(id, index, object) {
  // If there is more then one li with this ID #...
  if($('li[data-id="' + id + '"]').length > 1){

    // get all items with this id
    var items = $('li[data-id="' + id + '"]');

    // Get totel number of items with this id
    var numItems = $('li[data-id="' + id + '"]').length;

    // Create a random number between 0 and the number of items with this id
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()* numItems);

    // Make all inactive...
    $('li[data-id="' + id + '"]').addClass('inactive');

    // ...except one 
    $(items[rand]).removeClass('inactive');
  }
});
```