# All blog post should fade in when scrolling except the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

the first blog post should show and then the others will fade-in as you scroll down. On the Home page the first one doesn't display until I scroll - which is what I don't want. My code is below including css to display that first blog post:

```
function sectionFadeIn() {
$('.fadein').each(function() {
    var top_of_object = $(this).offset().top + 50;
    var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    if (bottom_of_window > top_of_object) {
        $(this).animate({ 'opacity': '1'}, 1000);
     }
})
```

}

My CSS:

```
.fadein {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .fadein:first-of-type {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

The website: tazkhatri.com

Comment: First-of-type doesn't work that way - you have to pass it an element type (e.g. div, p), not a class. Can you use :first-child instead maybe?

Comment: Hello, I tried :first-child but unfortunately I'm still getting the same result!

Comment: Can you just remove the `.fadein` class from the first post?

Comment: Do you have to use `.each`? I think you can remove that iterator because the `$('.fadein')` alone should capture all of the items you want.

Comment: Is this function within a `$(window).scroll` callback?

Comment: Hey Brett DeWoody, yes it is.

Comment: Did any of the solutions below solve your issue?

Comment: Hey Brett, unfortunately not. I just nixed the idea.

Answer (score 1):

you could use

```
$('.fadein').not('.fadein:first-child').each(function() {...}
```

*Update: Just spotted the link to your live code.*

The above code will not work as your .fadein elements are not all child elements. See this post on how to target all elements except for the first instance of that element. [jQuery select all except first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259393/jquery-select-all-except-first)

Comment: You'll need to update your css too. Get rid of what you have and just use .fadein:not(:first-child){opacity:0}

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the code in the original post has been simplified, but the `sectionFadeIn` function would need to be within a `$(window).scroll()` callback, like:

```
function sectionFadeIn() {
  $('.fadein').each(function() {
    var top_of_object = $(this).offset().top + 50;
    var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    if (bottom_of_window > top_of_object) {
      $(this).animate({ 'opacity': '1'}, 1000);
    }
  })
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
  sectionFadeIn();
});
```

However, I think we can simplify this by having CSS handle the `opacity` animation. Here's how we'll do it:

1. We'll use a simple throttle to prevent the function from firing with every little scroll.
2. Find the hidden elements, calculate their position
3. If the position is above the bottom of the window, add a `visible` class
4. Setup the CSS to animate the opacity of the element

```js
var scrollWait = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (!scrollWait) {
    scrollWait = true;
    var hidden = $('.fadein:not(.visible)');
    var windowBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    hidden.each(function() {
      var elTop = $(this).offset().top + 50;
      
      if (windowBottom > elTop) {
        $(this).addClass('visible');
      }
    });
  }
});

setInterval(function() {
  if(scrollWait) {
    scrollWait = false;
  }
}, 200);
```

```css
.post {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.fadein {
  opacity: 0;
  will-change: opacity;
}

.fadein:first-child {
  opacity: 1;
}

.visible:not(:first-child) {
  animation: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main>
  <div class="post fadein visible"></div>
  <div class="post fadein"></div>
  <div class="post fadein"></div>
  <div class="post fadein"></div>
  <div class="post fadein"></div>
  <div class="post fadein"></div>
  <div class="post fadein"></div>
  <div class="post fadein"></div>
  <div class="post fadein"></div>
  <div class="post fadein"></div>
  <div class="post fadein"></div>
  <div class="post fadein"></div>
  <div class="post fadein"></div>
  <div class="post fadein"></div>
  <div class="post fadein"></div>
</main>
```